# How to read logs from file in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I want to read Apache logs in kafka and then further process in to Spark Streaming.I am new to kafka. As far as I have understand I have to write a producer class to read logs file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by creating a connector which sources each line of the log file into the Kafka topic. Check out the example here:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#connect-developing-simple-connector

Comment: and then I can write consumer file to send these logs in Spark streaming.