# IBM AIX - Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, aix, nxlog

I have a case with IBM AIX, need to send syslogs, logs from file and maybe appslogs to Apache Kafka, is it possible ?
I try search something about nxlog, but he don't have output to Kafka for AIX
any other solutions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read logs from file in kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508901/how-to-read-logs-from-file-in-kafka)

Comment: @JimWright, Topic "How to read logs from file in Kafka?" does not resolve my problem

Comment: "need to send syslogs, logs from file and maybe appslogs to Apache Kafka"?

Answer (score 1):

You can stream all sorts of data into (and out of) Apache Kafka using **Kafka Connect**, which is part of Apache Kafka. There's a list of [connectors here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/), including [log files](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) and [syslog](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-syslog).

Comment: The file connector does not handle rolling files (a common practice with log files)